# JavaScript test if url does NOT contain some text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, url

I found many option of checking if the URL contains some text but I am trying to do the opposite.

How can I start a function if the URL DOES NOT contain 'text'?

Here is what I started with that does fire the function but only if the url contains it:

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('text') > -1){ 
alert('URL should not have "text" in it');
    }
```

I tried adding a '!' and a 'NOT' in front of the '(document...' but I guess that's not it.

Comment: I strongly recommend https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf it´s very good documented.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

```
if (document.location.href.indexOf('text') === -1){ 
    alert('URL should not have "text" in it');
}
```

Comment: Heh, I think so too. It works..

I got my own version to work too after I created it but yours is much shorter:

if (document.location.href.indexOf('RecordID') > -1){ 
 alert('This url contains "text"');
} else {
 alert('This url DOES NOT contains "text"');
}

Answer (score 0):

```
if(document.URL.indexOf("YourText") <= -1){
    "Check"
}
```

Comment: Is there any situation where `.indexOf()` would return a number smaller than -1? (rhetorical question)

Comment: The OP got an answer 1 year ago, and accepted it (that means it worked). Why post another so late, just duplicating the other answer, with no explanation to how it works whatsoever?

Comment: Techniques change over the years and different problems may have appeared. It is a valid question.

Answer (score 0):

It's better to use `document.location.pathname.includes('text')` simple reason it won't be maintaining the index returned and will be a simple boolean `true/false` in case of includes
In your case simply :-

```
if(!document.location.pathname.includes('text')){
  //You condition Code goes here
}
```

Note:- You can always use `/text` or `/text/` instead of test if you know the text will come in the middle of an URL to make it better as `othertext` will become false in that case.